# How do I change the screensaver on FreeNAS 8?

Tags: screensaver, freenas

The default screensaver is annoying. I would be happier with a blank screen.

Comment: Since FreeNAS is FreeBSD, why not follow instructions for adding console screensavers and modifying your /etc/rc.conf file

Comment: Thank you for the help. Can you give any resources on how to do this and if it works for FreeNAS?

Comment: There is this little Gem http://www.freebsddiary.org/screensaver.php and there is this more lengthy article http://www.marksanborn.net/freebsd/adding-a-console-screensaver-to-freebsd-70/ and the handbook http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ but honestly, I've never done any of this.  I can only assume that since it is FreeBSD at it's core, if you look for these files and settings and find them, then changing them will work.  If the screensaver files themselves are not present, you could import them from an installation of FreeBSD.